# Accessing an input tag from a form tag of a different html file and printing it in a new html file three times

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, input

**First HTML file**:

I have a simple input tag in a form that asks the user to type anything(*text*) he wants.

**Second HTML file**:

Accesses the input inside the form in first HTML file and prints it three times.

**First HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
        <title>First HTML</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <form>
           input <input id="silly" type="text" placeholder="Enter something silly">
       </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

**Second HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>Second HTML</title>
      </head>
      <body>
         <p id="printHere">print the input here 3 times</p>
      </body>
   </html>
```

***The JQuery I'm trying to use in second HTML***

```
$.get('a.html', null, function(text){
    alert($(text).find('.silly'));
});
```

Comment: You know for actually changing the contents of the files (in this case html) you would need a server side language like php not javascript. But if you're just dynamically changing for temporary purpose while it is being displayed, then okay you can make use of the GET parameter to pass values or you can make use of localStorage.

Comment: The langugae I'm working with is bash. But I'm required to write the conditional statements in javascript. I tried mixing javascript and bash by using cat <EOF and EOF whenever necessary but didn't turn out good

Comment: I'm using QUERY_STRING to access the input I have in array form by default

Comment: Add your Jquery code.

Comment: can this so ?  $.get('firstHtml.html', null, function(text){
    alert($(text).find('.silly'));
});  What does text mean?

Comment: ok got it . It means the text format of whatever I'm accessing